# install nodejs on openwrt

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I am trying to install nodejs on raspberry pi B+ running openwrt chaos calmer, I found this package (node_v0.12.7-2_brcm2708.ipk) at (https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/brcm2708/generic/packages/packages/) I couldn't install it directly on the raspi so I downloded it on my mac pc and deploy it to the raspi. When I try to run helloWorld.js script I got the following error:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# node /test/hello.js
```

`-ash: node: not found`

Comment: So the `node` executable is installed somewhere that's not in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have not installed the package.

If you can connect to the internet using your raspberry, try editing the /etc/opkg.conf to a working repository, then run opkg update, and opkg install .

If it is not possible you can install any package by the opkg package maanger:
opkg install

Answer (score 0):

Its because the file is dynamically linked. You have to set the linker options to statically link the libraries when generating an executable

Answer (score 0):

When building the image for your device, you can select and add the package with the command `make menuconfig`

the node package location in the menu is in the language section as explained here : https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/node

to build an image, you can use the procedure here : https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/build-system/start

Answer (score -1):

you have not installed `node` correctly!.. if you can't install directly try `putty` .you can connect a ***remote shell*** using your mac over wifi and install node from there.

1. [Installing putty on mac](http://codingsteps.com/installing-and-using-putty-on-mac-os-x/)
2. [Putty RaspberryPi remote connection](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/windows.md)